# DateTime null values

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, oledbdatareader

I have the following code that is supposed to check that a value in a data reader is not null. If it is then the method should return a null value or null DateTime for use later.

```
private static DateTime safeGetDateTime(OleDbDataReader dr, int idx)
    {
        if (!dr.IsDBNull(idx))
            return dr.GetDateTime(idx);

        else return DateTime.MinValue; 
    }
```

I have tried just returning null but as the methods return type is "DateTime", this did not work. I then tried to return DateTime.MinValue if a null is picked up by the datareader. This has given me the following error:

> SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: use a nullable `DateTime?`

Comment: If you notice that the error is from `SqlDateTime` not `DateTime`, I think you'll find that it's throwing the exception on the `return dr.GetDateTime(idx);` line, not the `return DateTime.MinValue;` line.

Comment: @MichaelL. That seems unlikely, as the value in the database is already a valid SQL date. I suspect that the OP has misunderstood the location of the error, and it is actually when the value is being written to the database, rather than when it is being read from the database.

Comment: Are you sure this is the location of the error? The error is likely happening when the value is being written to the database (though your previous null-conversion error would have happened here, before you changed the code).

Comment: @JeffreyLWhitledge Good point, and you're right.

Answer (score 4):

You get this error because of DateTime.MinValue differeneces in CLR and SQL server.

I suggest you to use [Nullable Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Let the method return a `Nullable<DateTime>`, then you can return `null`:

```
private static DateTime? safeGetDateTime(OleDbDataReader dr, int idx)
{
    if (!dr.IsDBNull(idx))
        return dr.GetDateTime(idx);
    else 
        return null; 
}
```

You still have to check the return value, your error suggests that you are using this value in another sql query as parameter, you have to assign `DBNull.Value` in the `null`-case.

```
DateTime? date = safeGetDateTime(reader, columnOrdinal);
yourSqlParameter.Value = date.HasValue ? (object)date.Value : DBNull.Value;
```

Answer (score 2):

The error must come from you assigning [DateTime.MinValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue(v=vs.90).aspx) to a `SqlDateTime` parameter.

**DateTime.MinValue:**

> The value of this constant is equivalent to 00:00:00.0000000, January 1, 0001.

**SqlDateTime.MinValue**

> The minimum valid date for a SqlDateTime structure is January 1, 1753.

So if you are going to use the return of this method in a `SqlDateTime` parameter, you can try returning [SqlDateTime.MinValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqldatetime.minvalue(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
return (DateTime)System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue;
```

Alternatively, you can try using `DateTime?` as the returning type, so you can return `null`

Answer (score 0):

You can keep `safeGetDateTime` just as it is, but when you write the value back to the database, you should check if it is the `DateTime.MinValue`. If it is, then you should write a null value to the database.

```
if (value == DateTime.MinValue)
{
    comm.Parameters.AddWithvalue("@mydate", null);
}
else 
{
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mydate", value);
}
```